# Trying to copy a file from my computer to another computer on the same network

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-copying

Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      File.Copy(@"C:\Documents and Settings\subhayan\Desktop\QBpluginlink.txt", @"\\10.10.10.148\C:\QBpluginlink.txt", true);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
   }
}
```

when this code is executed I get the exception

> The given path's format is not supported

can anyone tell me where I may have mistaken ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the `C:` in the UNC-path that you want to copy the file to. Either you change this to be a valid share on the target computer or you use an administrative share (if these are enabled and the account has sufficient rights to do so):

```
@"\\10.10.10.48\ValidShareName\QBpluginlink.txt", // Valid share name

@"\\10.10.10.48\C$\QBpluginlink.txt", // Administrative share
```

Comment: @Markus 
Is there a way to provide username and password with the path ?

Comment: You can also run the code under a specific account if you impersonate this account. But in this case, you are responsible for storing the credentials in a secure way. It is much easier if you can first make it work in Windows Explorer e.g. by giving access permissions to the application account or by specifying the credentials and saving them in Windows password store. If the basic access is in place, your application does not need to do anything special.

Answer (score 2):

That path wouldn't work even if you tried it in windows explorer. If you have permission try a proper file share UNC path:

`\\10.10.10.148\c$\QBpluginlink.txt`

Note the `c$`, it is a default admin share setup by windows to access the `C:` drive - but you will need the correct permissions. Alternatively create a specific share as per the answer by Markus.

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN:

```
    string fileName = @"QBpluginlink.txt";
    string sourcePath = @"C:\Documents and Settings\subhayan\Desktop";
    string targetPath =  @"\\10.10.10.148\C$";

    // Use Path class to manipulate file and directory paths.
    string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
    string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);

    // To copy a folder's contents to a new location:
    // Create a new target folder, if necessary.
    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
    {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
    }

    // To copy a file to another location and 
    // overwrite the destination file if it already exists.
    System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
```

Please make sure you have an access to copy a file going to the server

Answer (score 0):

The destination has to be a valid file path, in your case a valid UNC path.

"\10.10.10.48\C:\QBpluginlink.txt" is not valid because you are referencing the c: drive of that comoputer, you need to create a shared folder in your destination server and use that path.

Alternatively use the default drive share: e.g. \10.10.10.48\C$\QBpluginlink.txt